# Adapter reload Android

Tags: android, listview, caching, adapter

I was thinking. What is the best way to save a custom adapter before activity onDestroy() is called? I want to populate an adapter with items (texts and images) and set it to listView. However, I don't want to repopulate the adapter again when the user navigate away from that activity and comes back as repopulation is too time consuming. I want to save the adapter value somewhere before the activity inDestroy() is called and check if it empty on activity onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, adapter is a pretty complex object and its persistent saving may be a difficult task (if possible at all). The more common approach is saving persistently your dataset.

You worry about the population time, but serialization-deserialization of the adapter is going to take time as well, and apparently much more time then the dataset alone, because it includes the dataset in it.

**EDIT**

Small conceptual example on saving your dataset to `SharedPreferences` using Gson library ([more on it](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples)) (just one of the ways to persistently save your data):

```java
    public void saveData(ArrayList<YourDataType> data) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String dataJson = gson.toGson(data);
        getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                                                                .putString("key_data", dataJson)
                                                                .apply();
    }

    public ArrayList<YourDataType> restoreData() {
        String dataJson =
                getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .getString("key_data", "empty");
        ArrayList<YourDataType> data = null;

        if (!dataJson.equals("empty")) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourDataType>>() {}.getType();
            data = gson.fromJson(dataJson, collectionType);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: But is there a way to save the individual Arraylist components that make up the adapter so I don't have to repopulate the adapter? The adapter is populated after parsing an XML file from the web and I don't want to re parse everytime the user is returning to the activity. I can populate if the app runs for the first time. Thanks for your comment @ Android777

Comment: @saintjab yep, please see my amended answer with a small example of usage

Answer (score 1):

You can save adapter data inside application class and when activity is recreated check Application class arraylist is empty or not. If not empty
assign it to adapter.

But storing it inside global variable i.e Application class may make your app heavy on heap memory.

```
public class GlobalState extends Application {
ArraList<Type> arrayList = new ArrayList<type>();
public void setArraylist(ArraList<Type> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}
public ArraList<Type> getArrayList() {
    return arrayList;
}
public int dataSize() {
    return arrayList.size();
}
```

}